# vb.net Interface and a Classes

Tags: vb.net, class, interface

I have a class which has a variety of details, as follows:

Vehicle Name
Vehicle Address

VEHICLE Percentage: 10

I need to somehow use an Interface for another version, SpecialVehicle.

Special Vehicle has a different Percentage,  for example 15.

How can I integrate that in an interface? I just don't understand them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wouldn't use an interface; you would just inherit from `Vehicle`. Assuming `Percentage` is a `Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Percentage() As Integer` (if it's not `Overridable` and a `Property`, make it so), override it in `SpecialVehicle` like so:

```
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Percentage() As Integer
    Get
        Return 15
    End Get
End Property
```

Comment: So if my code looked like
Public Class Vehicle
...Percentage = 5
End Class
Should I make another Class, inherit from Vehicle, and use the property you specified?

Comment: @Mombassa: Almost! You have to make `Percentage` a property. It looks the same as the one for `SpecialVehicle`, except instead of `Overrides`, it's `Overridable`, and instead of `15` it's `10`.